# While Loop Fail - Caesar Cipher

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, shift, encryption

I'm having a problem where when I ask my program to quit out it prints like I ask it to, however shows my menu of options as well continuously.

So I'm getting this:

```
>>> 
(S)huffle a message.
(U)nshuffle a message.
(Q)uit program.
Choose a option to begin: q
Goodbye!
(S)huffle a message.
(U)nshuffle a message.
(Q)uit program.
Choose a option to continue:
```

Where I want it to display this if I choose 'q':

```
>>> 
(S)huffle a message.
(U)nshuffle a message.
(Q)uit program.
Choose a option to begin: q
Goodbye!
```

Here is my complete code, please explain why my menu is reprinting, did I make my while loop wrong, or is something out of place in my code?

```
def hw8():

    print('(S)huffle a message.')
    print('(U)nshuffle a message.')
    print('(Q)uit program.')

    x = input('Choose a option to begin: ')

    if x == 'Q' or x == 'q':
        print('Goodbye!')

    while x != 'q' or 'Q' :

        if x == 'S' or x == 's':
            y = input('Enter a message to shuffle: ')

            q1 = ''

            for i in y:
                if ord(i) in range(65,90) or ord(i) in range(97,122):
                    q = chr(ord(i) + 1)
                    q1 = q1 + q
                elif ord(i) == 90:
                    q = chr(ord(i) + 7)
                    q1 = q1 + q
                elif ord(i) == 122:
                    q = 'A'
                    q1 = q1 + q
                else:
                    q = i
                    q1 = q1 + q
            print(q1)



        if x == 'U' or x == 'u':
            f = input('Enter a message to unshuffle: ')

            t2 = ''

            for i in f:
                if ord(i) in range (66,91) or ord(i) in range(98,123):
                    t = chr(ord(i) - 1)
                    t2 = t2 + t
                elif ord(i) == 65:
                    t = 'z'
                    t2 = t2 + t
                elif ord(i) == 97:
                    t = 'Z'
                    t2 = t2 + t
                else:
                    t = i
                    t2 = t2 + t

            print(t2)

        print('(S)huffle a message.')
        print('(U)nshuffle a message.')
        print('(Q)uit program.')

        x = input('Choose a option to continue: ')


hw8()
```

I want the program to display the menu after shuffling a message, or unshuffling a message, as well as at the beginning, but not after the user has asked to quit the program by choosing 'q'.

---

Edited code:

```
def hw8():

    print('(S)huffle a message.')
    print('(U)nshuffle a message.')
    print('(Q)uit program.')

    x = input('Choose a option to begin: ')

    while x != 'q' or x != 'Q' :

        if x == 'S' or x == 's':
            y = input('Enter a message to shuffle: ')

            q1 = ''

            for i in y:
                if ord(i) in range(65,90) or ord(i) in range(97,122):
                    q = chr(ord(i) + 1)
                    q1 = q1 + q
                elif ord(i) == 90:
                    q = chr(ord(i) + 7)
                    q1 = q1 + q
                elif ord(i) == 122:
                    q = 'A'
                    q1 = q1 + q
                else:
                    q = i
                    q1 = q1 + q
            print(q1)



        if x == 'U' or x == 'u':
            f = input('Enter a message to unshuffle: ')

            t2 = ''

            for i in f:
                if ord(i) in range (66,91) or ord(i) in range(98,123):
                    t = chr(ord(i) - 1)
                    t2 = t2 + t
                elif ord(i) == 65:
                    t = 'z'
                    t2 = t2 + t
                elif ord(i) == 97:
                    t = 'Z'
                    t2 = t2 + t
                else:
                    t = i
                    t2 = t2 + t

            print(t2)

        print('(S)huffle a message.')
        print('(U)nshuffle a message.')
        print('(Q)uit program.')

        x = input('Choose a option to continue: ')

        if x == 'Q' or x == 'q':
            print('Goodbye!')


hw8()
```

New Output:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 

(S)huffle a message.
(U)nshuffle a message.
(Q)uit program.
Choose a option to begin: s
Enter a message to shuffle: hello
ifmmp
(S)huffle a message.
(U)nshuffle a message.
(Q)uit program.
Choose a option to continue: q
Goodbye!
(S)huffle a message.
(U)nshuffle a message.
(Q)uit program.
Choose a option to continue:
```

Comment: In addition to the correct answers you could consider using a `while x.lower() != 'q': ... else: print ('Goodbye')` . That saves an if statement and expresses the intent more clearly in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
while x != 'q' or 'Q' :
```

The problem is that `Q` itself will always return `True`, so the expression will always be true. Try changing the line with:

```
while x != 'q' and x != 'Q' :
```

Comment: This helps but however if I shuffle a message, and then attempt to quit, the program stops without printing the quit message of "Goodbye!". Why's this?

Comment: This is because the `print("Goodbye!")` comes before the while-loop. You can add `if x == 'q' or x == 'Q': print("Goodbye!")` to the bottom of the while loop.

Comment: I tryed to put it at the bottom of the while loop, however now it's reprinting the menu again.

Comment: I added my edited code to the original post at the bottom, as well as the output I'm now receiving.

Comment: Make sure that it is inside the while loop, right after the `input`

Comment: It has to be `and` instead of `or` on the line where your while-loop starts. If not, one of the conditions will always be true!

Comment: After changing my while loop to "and" instead of "or" this fixed my problem. Thanks so much mart0903! :)

Answer (score 4):

`x != 'q' or 'Q'` is being handled as `(x != 'q') or 'Q'`, and 'Q' is always True.

It would better be:
`x not in 'qQ'` or `x.lower() != 'q'`

Comment: You are repeating yourself in the code, which is a bad habit. I suggest you do everything in a `while True:` loop, and if the user wants to quit, `break`. This sort of issue with 'while' loops comes up frequently.