# How to user input while defining function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to calculate area of cuboid. I had tried this function:

```
def area(l, b, h):
    return l*b*h
```

But I want prompt to ask user to input values like

```
lx = float(input("Enter Length"))
```

How to define this function?

Comment: Do you mean something like: `def area(): return float(input("Enter Length: "))*float(input("Enter Length: "))*float(input("Enter Length: "))`?

Answer (score 3):

You already have 2/3 of the answer. 
The first thing you did is called "defining" the function. Now you just need to "call" it with the value the user inputs. I assume you also want the user to define base and height variables.

```
# Define function
def area(l, b, h):
    return l*b*h

# Take user input
lx = float(input("Enter Length"))
bx = float(input("Enter Base"))
hx = float(input("Enter Height"))

# Call function with user input
a = area(lx, bx, hx)

# Display results to user
print(a)
```

You could also ask for input inside the function itself, and call the function from within the `print` statement:

```
# Define function
def area():
    # Take user input
    lx = float(input("Enter Length"))
    bx = float(input("Enter Base"))
    hx = float(input("Enter Height"))
    return lx*bx*hx

# Call function and display results to user
print(area())
```

---

For extra credit, you may want to [check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35317608/5903421) that the user input is valid (that they are not entering letters instead of numbers, for example).